# Автоматическое выполнение функции

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, время

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, а то вообще не доходит ни как. Как на AJAX/JS сделать, чтобы автоматически срабатывала функция. У меня стоит таймер и по окончанию таймера выполняется функция, а мне надо чтобы это был запрос в php файл.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

function get_timer() {

  var date_close = '<?php echo $dateclosew; ?>';
  var date_t = new Date(date_close);


  var curOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
  var utc = (curOffset > 0 ? "-" + curOffset : (-curOffset));

  var date = new Date();
  date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + date.getTimezoneOffset());
  var timer = date_t - date;

  if(date_t > date) {

    var min = parseInt(timer/(1000*60))%60;
    if(min < 10) {
      min = '0' + min;
    }
    min = min.toString();

    var sec = parseInt(timer/1000)%60;
    if(sec < 10) {
      sec = '0' + sec;
    }
    sec = sec.toString();


    if(min[1] == 9 && 
      sec[0] == 5 && 
      sec[1] == 9) {
      animation($("#min0"),min[0]);
    }
    else {
      $("#min0").html(min[0]);
    }
    if(sec[0] == 5 && sec[1] == 9) {
      animation($("#min1"),min[1]);
    }
    else {
      $("#min1").html(min[1]);
    }

    if(sec[1] == 9) {
      animation($("#sec0"),sec[0]);
    }
    else {
      $("#sec0").html(sec[0]);
    }
    animation($("#sec1"),sec[1]); 
    setTimeout(get_timer,1000);
  }
  else {

    [ЗДЕСЬ ВЫПОЛНЯЕТСЯ ФУНКЦИЯ]

  }
}
function animation(vibor,param) {
  vibor.html(param)
    .css({'marginTop':'-20px','opacity':'0'})
    .animate({'marginTop':'0px','opacity':'1'});
}
get_timer();
});
```

Я пробовал сделать так, но он не выполняет эту функция как заканчивается таймер. Сам таймер сделан правильно и если вставить `alert('hello');`, то он выдаст сообщение:

```
$.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'obr/file.php',
        })
```

Comment: _...по окончанию таймера выполняется функция, а мне надо чтобы это был запрос в php файл_ - в чем проблема поставить вместо функции запрос в PHP файл?

Comment: @lolbas Так а как? В этом то и дело что я не знаю как.

Comment: Вот так: `Ctrl+C` кода AJAX и `Ctrl+V`, чтобы вставить где надо. Другой проблемы при данном оформлении поста я не вижу. Или описывайте проблему другим путем

Comment: @lolbas ну то есть я понимаю ajax скрипт написан правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допустим **obr/file.php**:

```
<?php die( date('H:m:s d.m.Y') );
```

И **[ЗДЕСЬ ВЫПОЛНЯЕТСЯ ФУНКЦИЯ]** это:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'obr/file.php',
}).done(function(a){
    // Обрабатываем ответ
    console.log( "success:" );
    console.log(a);
}).error(function(e){
    // Обрабатываем ошибки
    console.log( "error:" );
    console.log(e);
});
```

Если, как писали, алерт отрабатывает, и есть доступ к *obr/file.php* из *JS* скрипта, то в консоле должны увидеть время с датой.
Иначе, если какой то сбой, то увидите в консоли ошибку, которую прикрепите к Вашему вопросу с пометкой, к примеру, **update1**.